# How to pass class method as a parameter before the instance is declared?

Tags: java

What I want to do is like this. My question is how can I call tm.test in inner.

```
// TestMain is a class implemented handler

public void outer() {
    inner(TestMain::test);  // call inner
}

public void inner(handler h) {
    TestMain tm = new TestMain();
    //invoke tm.h(), i.e. invoke tm.test() in this example
}

public interface handler<M> {
    void entitySelector();
}
```

- I know how to call tm.test in inner if tm is declared in method outer, i.e. pass the function as tm::test
- But I have to declare the instance every time I call inner.

Answer (score 1):

Simply spoken: you can't. And even it would be possible, you shouldn't do something like that.

There is the "principle of least surprise": you don't that people reading your code tell you "wtf?!" because your code surprises them.

In other words: you should step back and see if your design really makes sense this way. Can't you use a fixed `tm` instance for example; one that sits as field on your class; instead of being a local variable in your method?

Comment: Thank you even it's a 'no'.